Is there a way to disable AlpineJS directives irreversibly under a given node?
AlpineJS is a great tool for doing minor interactivity in a concise and local manner. However, in so doing, it requires evaluating Javascript code in its attribute values, and so is incompatible with a strong CSP as a safety net against XSS attacks.
Of course, the first line of defense is to rigorously sanitize and escape all user-provided data before rendering it. However, this is a fallible process, and thus we have CSP and so forth as safety nets. Some other libraries provide similar safety-net options; e.g. HTMX has the hx-disable attribute, which disables HTMX processing of all child elements and can't be reversed from within those child elements.
Is there any similar option for AlpineJS? The x-ignore directive is similar, but this appears to only work under an existing x-data directive.

AlpineJs ignores nodes outside x-data by default

Yes, but in the case of XSS the attacker can just put in his own x-data and then execute code. I'm looking for a way to suppress processing of new x-data attributes.

Give a practical example please

Any user using your application has access to modify the client HTML and execute scripts. Trying to prevent this is basically a waste of time, because you cannot simply close all backdoors. I see no reason as to why you would need or even want to do this. Whatever malicious code that can be executed, it should be validated server side.

The point of this is similar to that of setting the CSP header. It's an extra layer of security against a server-side bug in escaping/whitelisting. The point is to make XSS impossible even if an attacker found a way around escaping for user-supplied data.
